# How to set up SSHD to allow login using public key authentication?

Tags: ssh

I've been trying to set my vps to use SSH keys for login instead of password. I've been reading tutorial after tutorial on how to set this up but I just can't set it up right.

So what I have done so far is the following

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
af:3a:f2:75:5f:c2:67:c8:ad:1d:0a:ab root@localhost
```

Copied Public Key into authorized_keys

```
cp root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The issue is, how do I login via this key? Do I save the private key on notepad? Because if SSH key logs me in via ip, I don't think I can login because my ip is dynamic . Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `id_rsa.pub` have to be added to the file `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` *on the machine that you want to log into* as root. On that ("target") machine, `sshd` also has to be configured to allow public key authentication. See sshd_config(5).

After this, you `ssh` as user `root` from some other machine to the target machine (by name or IP address, it doesn't matter). If you have protected the private key file `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` with a password then `ssh` asks you for the password so that it can read the private key.

Comment: jdthood let say I didn't provide an password for the private key and I go to my friend house and use putty to login my vps . Do I need to provide the private key? If so where?

Comment: You would need to provide the private key. You could consider carrying the `id_rsa` file with you on a USB stick; then you do `ssh -i /path/path/path/id_rsa myhost`. But in that case I would advise you at least to password-protect `id_rsa`. And even then, if you lose the USB stick then you should discontinue use of that keypair.

Answer (score 0):

If you present an authorized key, the default configuration let you in regardless of where you come from.

Comment: ok , How do you present an authorized key? If i'm logging in putty via window . How do I present this private key?

Comment: You need to understand the concept of public/private keys thoroughly - I recommend reading up on the subject.  But for putty, you need to generate a keypair on the the Windows machine in a form suitable for openssh, and _ADD_ the public key to the authorized_keys file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'ssh-copy-id', a nice and simple way to copy a key to a remote server with correct permissions etc...

$ ssh-copy-id username@server